# During Temple times, who can butcher a kosher animal?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, slaughter-shochet-shecht

During the Temple Times, for the purpose of consumption, can any Jew butcher a kosher animal or must the animal be butchered by a Cohen or a Levi?

I would appreciate a rabbinical source.

I just thought that a cohen or levi would be more qualified or trained to slaughter than an yisraelite (for the purpose of sacredness, purity ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92245/discussion-between-al-berko-and-ninamag).

Comment: Regarding slaughter for korbanot in particular: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27157/

Answer (score 14):

Any Jew, not necessarily a kohen or levi, can slaughter an animal, with few exceptions ([Chullin 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Chullin.1?lang=bi)):

> הַכֹּל שׁוֹחֲטִין וּשְׁחִיטָתָן כְּשֵׁרָה, חוּץ מֵחֵרֵשׁ, שׁוֹטֶה, וְקָטָן, שֶׁמָּא יְקַלְקְלוּ בִשְׁחִיטָתָן
>
> Anyone [may] slaughter - and his slaughter is valid - except for a deaf-mute, a shoteh [a person who exhibits signs demonstrating a lack of ability to think clearly], or a minor, lest they spoil the slaughter.

This is said about non-consecrated animals slaughtered to be eaten, but it is even the case for sacrificial animals ([Zevachim 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Zevachim.3?lang=bi)):

> כָּל הַפְּסוּלִין שֶׁשָּׁחֲטוּ, שְׁחִיטָתָן כְּשֵׁרָה. שֶׁהַשְּׁחִיטָה כְשֵׁרָה בְּזָרִים, בְּנָשִׁים, וּבַעֲבָדִים, וּבִטְמֵאִים
>
> If people who are ineligible [to serve in the Temple] slaughtered [an offering], their slaughtering is valid, since slaughtering is valid if performed by non-priests, by women, by slaves, and by impure individuals.

Comment: under the topic/rule of slaughter, are chickens (or winged kosher fowls) and fish (or any water-based animal with fins-and-scales) included?

Comment: @ninamag Fish are not slaughtered. Chicken are slaughtered by anyone, but I don't know of a source that explicitly says so